# ONE question regular expression PHP

Tags: php, regex

Count character '_' in start line

example :

```
subject = '_abcd_abc';   // return 1
or 
subject = '__abcd_abc';  // return 2
or 
subject = '___abcd_abc';  // return 3
```

everyone help me ~
I use PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
return preg_match('/^_+/', $str, $match) ? strlen($match[0]) : 0;
```

If `preg_match` finds a match, `$match[0]` will contain that match and `strlen($match[0])` returns the length of the match; otherwise the expression will return `0`.

Comment: preg_match stops searching after the first match is found.

Comment: Whoops, I thought he wanted the total number of underscores used in the whole string. Never mind, I see.

Comment: @Peter Ajtai: Apparently he/she is just looking for the number of leading characters.

Comment: Yeah. I just didn't realize what they were after.

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure the start of the string contains `_`, you can do this with just `strspn()`:

```
echo strspn('___abcd_abc',  '_');
// -> 3
```

If there might be no leading underscores, you can still do this without a regex using `strlen` and `ltrim`:

```
strlen($str) - strlen(ltrim($str, "_"));
```

This counts the string length, then subtracts the string length without the underscores on the left, the result being the number of underscores.

- [strspn()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strspn.php)
- [ltrim()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php)
- [strlen()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)